# WPF MahApps.Metro Embedded Dll Resource not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll, mahapps.metro

my problem is that the embedded dlls of MahApps.Metro and MahApps.Metro.IconPacks are not working fine.

Used the Visual Studio debugger to check if they are getting loaded and it worked fine. If it could not load them the program would throw a xaml exception.

But for some reason the ResourceDictionaries which are merged are not working in runtime.

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AuTg.png)

[But looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1iL5.png)

(As you can see the text color is different and it is missing the icon on the right side => does not load the styles.)

It looks like the first picture if both Dll's are provided in the directory of the program.

My App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Launcher.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Launcher.Class.Converter"
         >

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatSlider.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks;component/Themes/IconPacks.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\ColorBrushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\CustomMetroWindow.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\CustomListView.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\NewsStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\TextImageBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\GlowMetroButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls\ToggleSwitchWin10.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Simple Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <converter:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
        <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converter:BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityCollapsedConverter" />
        <converter:MultiObjectToBooleanConverter x:Key="MultiObjectToBooleanConverter" />
        <converter:DownloadProgressToVisibilityConverter x:Key="DownloadProgressToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converter:MultiObjectToStatusBarColorConverter x:Key="MultiObjectToStatusBarColorConverter" />
        <converter:MultiBooleanConverter x:Key="MultiBooleanConverter" />
        <converter:MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converter:OpacityToBooleanConverter x:Key="OpacityToBooleanConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My Program.cs

```
[STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var resourceName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Dll." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
            if (!resourceName.Contains("resources"))
            {
                using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        var assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
                        stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                        return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Assembly requestedAssembly = args.RequestingAssembly;
                AssemblyName requestedAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
                while (true)
                {
                    // requesting name in format: %assemblyname%.resources
                    // rewrite to: %assemblyName%.%assemblyName%.%culture%.resources.dll
                    //
                    var baseName = requestedAssemblyName.Name.Substring(0, requestedAssemblyName.Name.Length - ".resources".Length);
                    var name = string.Format("{0}.Dll.Lang.{1}.{2}.resources.dll", baseName, requestedAssemblyName.CultureInfo.Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

                    // by default for resources the requestingAssembly will be null
                    Assembly asm = null;
                    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

                    // resources have the same name as their belonging assembly, so find by name
                    var parentName = requestedAssemblyName.Name.Substring(0, requestedAssemblyName.Name.Length - ".resources".Length);
                    // I'd love to use linq here, but Cecil starts fucking up when I do (null reference exception on assembly.Write)
                    // without a Linq query it works fine, though

                    // ReSharper disable once LoopCanBeConvertedToQuery
                    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                    {
                        if (assembly.GetName().Name == parentName)
                        {
                            asm = assembly;
                        }
                    }
                    if (asm == null)
                    {
                        // cannot find assembly from which to load
                        return null;
                    }
                    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
                    {
                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            return Assembly.Load(bytes);
                        }
                    }
                    // did not find the specific resource yet
                    // attempt to use the parent culture, this follows the .Net resource fallback system
                    // e.g. if sub resource de-DE is not found, then .Parent will be "de", if that is not found parent will probably be default resource
                    var fallback = requestedAssemblyName.CultureInfo.Parent.Name;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fallback))
                    {
                        // is empty if no longer a parent
                        // return null so .Net can load the default resource
                        return null;
                    }
                    var alteredAssemblyName = requestedAssemblyName.FullName;
                    alteredAssemblyName = alteredAssemblyName.Replace(string.Format("Culture={0}", requestedAssemblyName.CultureInfo.Name), string.Format("Culture={0}", fallback));

                    requestedAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(alteredAssemblyName);
                }
            }
            return null;
        };

        App.Main();
    }
```

The control

```
<TextBox x:Name="Username"
            Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{lex:Loc Key=LoginWindow.YourUsername}" Margin="0,20,0,9"
            Text="{Binding Config.AuthUsername}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding LoggingIn, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" TextAlignment="Justify"
            >
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextImageBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <VisualBrush>
                                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                    <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="User" Foreground="{StaticResource MainIconBrush}" />
                                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            </VisualBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me: (add all libraries as Embedded Resource and set startup object to this class)

```
 public class Program
    {
        private static Assembly ExecutingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        private static string[] EmbeddedLibraries =
            ExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(x => x.EndsWith(".dll")).ToArray();
        [STAThreadAttribute]

        public static void Main()
        {

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

            App.Main();

        }
        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            // Get assembly name
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

            // Get resource name
            var resourceName = EmbeddedLibraries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(assemblyName));
            if (resourceName == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Load assembly from resource
            using (var stream = ExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The project file portion was cut off previous answer.
Add this to project file

```
      <!--Then add this is project file.-->
<Target Name="EmbedReferencedAssemblies" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- get list of assemblies marked as CopyToLocal -->
      <AssembliesToEmbed Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.dll'" />
      <!-- add these assemblies to the list of embedded resources -->
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(AssembliesToEmbed)">
        <LogicalName>%(AssembliesToEmbed.DestinationSubDirectory)%(AssembliesToEmbed.Filename)%(AssembliesToEmbed.Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Embedding: @(AssembliesToEmbed->'%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)', ', ')" />
  </Target>
  <!-- no need to copy the assemblies locally anymore -->
  <Target Name="_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue you described and came across fix that resolves the issue.

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolveAssembly;
    }

    private static Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

        var path = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";
        if (assemblyName.CultureInfo.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == false) {
            path = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", assemblyName.CultureInfo, path);
        }

        using (var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path)) {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            var assemblyRawBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyRawBytes, 0, assemblyRawBytes.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyRawBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

> %(AssembliesToEmbed.DestinationSubDirectory)%(AssembliesToEmbed.Filename)%(AssembliesToEmbed.Extension)
>         
>       
>       '%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)',
>   ', ')" />

Comment: Please make sure to format your code the next time before posting. It is not very readable right now. :)